# Priority of a priority queue always needs to be integral?

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue

I'm just curious if I can have any other data type to give the priority? Like strings, floats, etc?

Comment: you don't specify a language? The answer is a resounding YES. You can do anything you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the abstract, any type with a reasonable [Strict Weak Ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) can be used as the priority in a priority queue. The language you are using will determine how to define this ordering: in C++, operator< is used in standard containers, in Java, the interface Comparable and function compareTo are typically used. Custom comparison functions are also often supported, which can compare elements in a manner different than the default.

Comment: And any other type can be used just as well (as long as it satisfies the container requirements of the underlying storage container). Only, then you'll need to specify the ordering predicate on construction. See my answer on how to do both approaches. (Hmm. just realized I was assuming C++; however, most other platform libraries have similar mechanisms to specify comparers, like e.g. in .NET)

Answer (score 1):

No.

The ordering element of a priority queue does not have to be integral.

Yes.

You can use whatever type you want, as long as two values of that type can be compared to determine their inherent ordering.

Basically, you can build a priority queue that uses whatever type you want, even a complex number if you can determine an ordering that makes sense for those.

There is, however, another, unasked, question here, for which the answer is:

Yes, most existing implementations of a priority queue will use an integer as the ordering element as that is the easiest, and most common, value used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fullblown C++ demo of how to queue SillyJobs, defined as

```
struct SillyJob
{
    std::string description;
    std::string priority;
    // ...
};
```

It does so in two ways: using the member `operator<` (default) and by passing an explicit comparison predicate to `priority_queue` constructor.

Let's see the output up-front:

```
Silly: (by description length)
LOW: very very long description
HIGH: short
------------------------------------------------------------
Not so silly: (by priority value)
HIGH: short
LOW: very very long description
```

See it live on **http://ideone.com/VEEQa**

```
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct SillyJob
{
    std::string description;
    std::string priority;

    SillyJob(const std::string& d, const std::string& p)
        : description(d), priority(p) { }

    bool operator<(const SillyJob& sj) const { return description.size() < sj.description.size(); }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SillyJob& sj)
    { return os << sj.priority << ": " << sj.description; }
};

static bool by_priority(const SillyJob& a, const SillyJob& b)
{
    static std::map<std::string, int> prio_map;
    if (prio_map.empty())
    {
        prio_map["HIGH"]   = 3;
        prio_map["MEDIUM"] = 2;
        prio_map["LOW"]    = 1;
    }

    return prio_map[a.priority] < prio_map[b.priority];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Silly: (by description length)" << std::endl;
    {
        // by description length (member operator<)
        std::priority_queue<SillyJob> silly_queue;

        silly_queue.push(SillyJob("short", "HIGH"));
        silly_queue.push(SillyJob("very very long description", "LOW"));

        while (!silly_queue.empty())
        {
            std::cout << silly_queue.top() << std::endl;
            silly_queue.pop();
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::string(60, '-') << "\nNot so silly: (by priority value)" << std::endl;
    {
        // by description length (member operator<)
        typedef bool (*cmpf)(const SillyJob&, const SillyJob&);
        typedef std::priority_queue<SillyJob, std::vector<SillyJob>, cmpf> not_so_silly_queue;

        not_so_silly_queue queue(by_priority);

        queue.push(SillyJob("short", "HIGH"));
        queue.push(SillyJob("very very long description", "LOW"));

        while (!queue.empty())
        {
            std::cout << queue.top() << std::endl;
            queue.pop();
        }
    }

}
```

PS. The `by_priority` comparison function is quite a good example of bad design, but bear in mind it was for demonstrational purposes only :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type for priority if the values of the type can be compared with each other.